# Jquery using selectors after a selector has been used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this:

```
<tr id="thisRow">
    <td>
        <label for="pen1">Pen 1</label><input type="checkbox" name="pen1" /><br />
        <label for="pen2">Pen 2</label><input type="checkbox" name="pen2" /><br />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I use this jquery to get the row:

```
function GetRow(value) {
   var row = $("#"+value);

}
```

Now I have the row in memory, I really want to start modify a few cells in that row and then adding it to a different table altogether...

So I want to do this for example:

```
function GetRow(value) {
    var row = $("#"+value);
    row.select("td:nth-child(2) input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {

});
}
```

I know its not correct but you get the idea!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can find the list of jQuery methods and their functionality here http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I was to hasty to click ask, and forgot to add the question!

Comment: jQuery doesn't have `select` method, it seems you are looking for `find()`.

Comment: Read about the [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

Comment: cheers @Boaz, all good now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`$.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`$.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/). Like this:

```
row.find("td:nth-child(2) input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
});
```

Comment: think i need to use clone on row though... it kinda moved it across!